# What's the deal with moving statues?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In episode 1, how are Ed and Cornello able to make the statues move? How is that alchemy? Is it possible that the revived birds are under same process, i.e., they are just moving but not alive?

Comment: This isn't really a valid answer...but the simplest answer is this: Artistic license on the part of the anime-writers. In neither the Manga nor the new Anime (Brotherhood) is there any example of Cornello or Ed animating statues. Nor does the manga show Cornello re-animating that bird. The red eyes of the bird imply it is a chimera, but it isn't clear how he made it 'alive' again as the topic is never really addressed.

Comment: as said @guildsbounty, it's likely du to the artistic licence, it makes cooler to animated the statues instead of only make them appear as in the canon (manga and FMA brotherhood). In universe you can't animate something with only one alchemy (likely possible with many but tiring, especially a statue, since an alchemy is likely need for each move) so it's a flaw according to the in universe alchemy laws.